# Customization of android / ios biometric authentication dialog

Tags: flutter, dart, user-interface, biometrics

Can I customize (change background color, center text, add new text) default biometric authentication dialog in ios / android? local_auth is used, customization from AndroidAuthMessages is not enough.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately, there is no way to customize the default `biometric` screen on devices because it comes with a default launcher provided by the operation system.

Answer (score 1):

There is no other way to customize the background color, center text, add new text but we can  customize the text shown there by the following code.

```
import 'package:local_auth_android/local_auth_android.dart';
import 'package:local_auth_ios/local_auth_ios.dart';

class biometrics{
final auth = LocalAuthentication();

Void authenticateUsingBiometrics() async {
bool result = await auth.authenticate(
  localizedReason: 'Need authentication to move on',
    authMessages: const <AuthMessages>[
      AndroidAuthMessages(
        signInTitle: 'Need authentication',
        cancelButton: 'No thanks',
      ),
      IOSAuthMessages(
        cancelButton: 'No thanks',
      ),
    ],
  options: AuthenticationOptions(biometricOnly: true)
 );}
```

[image]

[for further reference](https://pub.dev/packages/local_auth)